# Slurm restrict out of memory kill to current task

Tags: out-of-memory, slurm

I am using slurm to run multiple python scripts in parallel. Some of these might exceed the allocated memory per cpu, which causes an Out-Of-Memory error. This is my slurm script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1-1 #Run on a single node
#SBATCH --ntasks=10 #Create ten tasks
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1G

#Run task on each cpu, thus 10 tasks in total
srun python -u heavy_file.py
```

I then might get the following memory error:

```
slurmstepd: error: Detected 2 oom-kill event(s) in StepId=1603425.0. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler.
srun: error: cmp077: task 7: Out Of Memory
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=1603425.0
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 1603425.0 ON cmp077 CANCELLED AT 2022-11-08T10:25:33 ***
slurmstepd: error: Detected 2 oom-kill event(s) in StepId=1603425.batch. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler.
```

The problem is that, in this case, all tasks are killed. Is there any way of letting all other tasks created by srun continue, while only killing the step where the error actually occurs?